# AWS MSK configuration issue with Spring

Tags: spring-kafka, aws-msk

We recently migrated from self-managed Kafka instance to fully-managed AWS MSK cluster. We have only IAM based role-authentication enabled to connect to MSK cluster from local systems.

When I do telnet to the public url of the cluster, I get successful response, but when trying to start my java application, it fails due to different errors. Below is my KafkaConfiguration

Error :

```
Invalid login module control flag 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider' in JAAS config
```

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Value("${aws.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${aws.kafka.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.kafka.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secret);
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "AWS_MSK_IAM");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(" + awsCredentials + ")");
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secret);

        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "AWS_MSK_IAM");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(" + awsCredentials + ")");
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

**Consumer Configuration :**

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${aws.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${aws.kafka.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.kafka.secret}")
    private String secret;

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secret);

        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "AWS_MSK_IAM");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(" + awsCredentials + ")");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "iTopLight");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> rawKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one option to connect MSK with IAM auth.

Firstly you need to use this lib in your project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.msk</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-msk-iam-auth</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>        
</dependency>
```

Than, you need to provide AWS access credentials provider. First option you can use environment variable or using system property.

System property solution will look like.

```java
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${aws.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${aws.kafka.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.kafka.secret}")
    private String secret;

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", accessKey);
        System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", secret);

        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "AWS_MSK_IAM");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required");
        configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_CLIENT_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS, "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "iTopLight");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> rawKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

You can check [`aws-msiam-auth`](https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth/blob/main/src/main/java/software/amazon/msk/auth/iam/internals/MSKCredentialProvider.java#L124) project for providers.

Comment: I followed with System.setProperty method, now I am getting "Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata"

Comment: Check your MSK Security-Group.
you can check connection with telnet are you able to reach MSK or not?

Comment: Yes, I have whitelisted my local IP in the security group and also able to telnet through console. This is the URL I am trying : 

telnet b-2-public.itoplightkafka.nvcy00.c3.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com 9198

Comment: Whitelisting will not resolve if your MSK is in a private subnet and you are testing it from outside of AWS.

Comment: But now I deployed the code on EC2 instance which is in the same subnet....and still same error